# Access 2003, need code to import files, run spec to convert to text, then rename file

Tags: ms-access, import

I've had quite a hard time with this--can anyone help?
I need code for a command button that will import a file (the file will be different each time but will always be either txt. or csv), run an import specification that converts all data types to text (the spec is called SpecsTest), then call the table "Scrubbed" (not the original file name). I've also been unable to create a macro that works--the challenge has been that each time this is run the raw file name will be different.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't used Access, but have done this a lot with Excel. Try this:

```
Dim ds As FileDialog
Set ds = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
ds.Show
Dim path as String
path = ds.SelectedItems(1)
```

You'll have to add some check to ensure that a file was selected, etc, but this should get you on the right track.
BTW, you can configure default directories, filters, ... in the FileDialog so you should be able to limit the tendency of your users to screw up the import, but you never can tell.

Comment: +1 Just to confirm, the "FileDialog" approach can be used in MS Access as well.

Comment: Thanks so much for the import. I'm a bit of a novice so I'm having trouble retrofitting vansimke's code to my specific application. Could you provide any more suggestions?

Comment: Need more details of the application to provide more help. What is not working for you? Dialog not appearing, can't capture filename, ???